# Firing a blank vs live round from a gun

Tags: forces, projectile

When firing a gun, is there any difference between a blank round and a live round, aside from the obvious presence of a bullet exiting the muzzle? For example, does it sound different? Is there any effect on recoil? What other differences are there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about firearms not physics

Comment: The path of the ignition gas state (on a $P\,V$ diagram for example) will be significantly different, because in one case the gas is stoppered by a significant mass that the former must accelerate, whereas this is absent in the case of the "blank".

Comment: There could be some physics question hidden here (so I partially agree with John), but I think it's also too broad because there are too many variables to consider (depends on firearm type, chamber size, user, how it's being held, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There is less recoil, and less chamber pressure. Repeating actions usually do not have enough energy to cycle. The noise is comparable to a live round.

Note that a blank round does not mean "no discharge". More than a few people have been killed by the wadding and other debris - it just doesn't have any appreciable range.

Comment: Properly configured, gas-operated semi-automatic and automatic weapons cycle just fine with blanks. In the military (US) a "blank adaptor" is attached to the muzzle which constricts the gas flow out of the weapon. This raises the internal pressure to cycle the weapon.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast precisely my point - there is not enough energy available to cycle the action. You have to add a piece to get the chamber pressure up.